# Recorrer Array JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Necesito Recorrer un array JSON en PHP
me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
{
  "SU_Result": {
    "SU_BE": [
      {
        "proABREVIATURATITULO": "",
        "proAPELLIDOMATERNO": "",
        "proAPELLIDOPATERNO": "",
        "proNOMBRES": "",
        "proNRODOCUMENTO": "",
        "proPAIS": "",
        "proTIPODOCUMENTO": "",
        "proESPECIALIDAD": "",
        "proTITULOPROFESIONAL": "",
        "proUNIVERSIDAD": ""
      },
      {
        "proABREVIATURATITULO": "",
        "proAPELLIDOMATERNO": "",
        "proAPELLIDOPATERNO": "",
        "proNOMBRES": "",
        "proNRODOCUMENTO": "",
        "proPAIS": "",
        "proTIPODOCUMENTO": "",
        "proESPECIALIDAD": "",
        "proTITULOPROFESIONAL": "",
        "proUNIVERSIDAD": ""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Con lo que tienes, ya has conseguido convertirlo a array en PHP. ¿Qué es exáctamente lo que pretendes hacer con ello? Si sabes que la estructura siempre va a ser SUNEDU_GradoAcademicoResult->SUNEDU_BE->Array, puedes usar un foreach sobre éste último (http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Una forma directa sería: `foreach ($obj["SUNEDU_GradoAcademicoResult"]["SUNEDU_BE"] as $k => $v){echo "Llave: ".$k. " Valor: ".$v."<br />";}` Hay otras maneras de hacerlo.

Comment: el arreglo mostrado por esa pagina es imposible que lo recorras porque cuando accedes via curl lo tomara como un string, debes acomodar primero el arreglo del servidor

Comment: @JackNavaRow, si observas, [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php)  crea un **array asociativo** con los datos obtenidos, precisamente en la respuesta hay un `print_r` de dicho arreglo, resultado de esto: `$obj = json_decode($json, true);`.

Comment: @A.Cedano intenta recorrer esa forma el arreglo, no vas a poder porque te estan devolviendo los datos mal!

Comment: Considera que editar para eliminar conté ido bajando la calidad pudiera considerarse vandalismo

Answer (score 4):

Para iterar la matriz recomiendo usar un **foreach**

```
foreach($obj as $clave => $valor) {
    print "$clave => $valor\n";
}
```

Puedes anidarlos hasta llegar al detalle que necesitas

```
foreach($obj as $valor) {
    foreach($valor as $clave2 => $valor2) {
        print "$clave2 => $valor2\n";
    }
}
```

Más info: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php